# XML list element convert string to int

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I read in an XML file from the web, decoded it and put it into a tree for parsing:

```
data = openedurl.read()
xml = data.decode()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
```

I get back the following element for counts:

> <Element 'commentinfo' at 0x7fe9821c0040> <class
> 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>

I check the type and its a list:
<class 'list'>

The list is populated with numbers that are strings. The goal is to convert this from strings to ints.

I know I can do:

```
mylist =[]
for count in counts:
    mylist.append(int(count.text))
```

I was also able to do:

```
mylist = [int(count.text) for count in counts]
```

I was trying with use `map` but I was unsuccessful and I get:

```
counts = list(map(int, counts))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'
```

Is there a way to do this using `map`?
Also should I have not created a new list `mylist` for the comprehension and just do:

```
counts = [int(count.text) for count in counts]
```

I am just trying to better code and get better understanding of what and why.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the xml please?

Comment: [link]http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
i am just trying to sum up all the count elements

Comment: please check the code answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two cases, you do `count.text` to get the `text`. However, when using `map`, you merely apply the `int` function directly onto `count`, rather than `count.text`.

Since `count` is an `Element` object rather than a string, you get the error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'

If you want to use `map` to get the list of counts, you can use a [lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) inside the `map` like this:

```
mylist = list(map(lambda x: int(x.text), counts))
```

That way, the `int` function is applied to the string inside the `count` (in this case `x.text`).

As for your second question on

```
counts = [int(count.text) for count in counts]
```

versus

```
mylist = [int(count.text) for count in counts]
```

that is entirely your choice. If you want to re-use the original `counts` later on, then don't override it and instead  create a new `mylist`; otherwise, its perfectly fine to overrride the existing `counts`.

Comment: Thanks this really helps to wrap my head around these concepts

Answer (score 1):

PFB piece of code that will find the sum of all count elements:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
xml = data.decode()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

counts = tree.findall('.//count')

count_lst = []
sum = 0
for count in counts:
    count_lst.append(int(count.text))
    sum = sum + int(count.text)

print('count_lst: ', count_lst)
print('sum of all counts: ', sum)
```

output:

```
count_lst:  [97, 97, 90, 90, 88, 87, 87, 80, 79, 79, 78, 76, 76, 72, 72, 66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 61, 61, 59, 58, 57, 57, 54, 51, 49, 47, 40, 38, 37, 36, 36, 32, 25, 24, 22, 21, 19, 18, 18, 14, 12, 12, 9, 7, 3, 2]

sum of all counts:  2553
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something like that:

```
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
openedurl = urllib.request.urlopen(url,context=ctx
data = openedurl.read()
xml = data.decode()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

counts = tree.findall('.//count')


counts = [int(count.text) for count in counts]
print('Count:',len(counts))
print('Sum:',sum(counts))
```

Comment: cool. if answers helps, you can upvote the answer! thanks @sauce1173